# Mailto: multiple addresses using Cognos data item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cognos

I am trying to create a button that can send all clients in the list.

Once I hit the button, it can open my outlook and input all those clients email for me.

Right now, I only can display one email with javascript and the address is not from a data item.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>




<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    window.open('sample@abc.com');
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Another method is only for one email as well.

```
'<a href="mailto:'+[My team].[Email Address] +' ">'EMAIL</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

- Add a Repeater to your report.
- Add you email Query Item on it
- Add HTML Item before Repeater. Put inside

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function getListSeparator() {
  var list = ['a', 'b'], str;
  if (list.toLocaleString) {
      str = list.toLocaleString();
      if (str.indexOf(';') > 0 && str.indexOf(',') == -1) {
          return ';';
      }
  }
  return ',';
  }
  </script>
  <div id ="maillist">
  ```
- Insert HTML Item *inside* Repeater after your Data Item. Put inside

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript">document.write(getListSeparator())</script>
  ```
- Insert HTML Item after Repeater. Put inside

  ```
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  document.write('<a href="mailto:'+document.getElementById("maillist").innerText+'">EMAIL</a>')
  document.getElementById("maillist").style.display = 'none'
  </script>
  ```

Works fine in IE9 & Cognos 10.2, semicolon as a separator